# How to look up ZIP/Postal Code by City using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding, street-address, postal-code

How can I extract a Postal Code or ZIP of a place by giving [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html) a city on the map?

Basically I'm looking for a free verification service for checking completed addresses for accurate details.

I seem to remember the maps API can somehow provide a geographical point when given an address. Now I'm searching for a slightly reversed situation in order to validate the postal code typed in with a city.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **[Geocode](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding)** the address to get best match coordinates

and then Reverse Geocode the coordinates to compare zip.