# How to get city and postal code from google maps API?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to get city and postal code from google maps API.My code look like this

```
if (place.address_components) {                    
code = [place.address_components[0].types[0].postal_code];
alert(code);
document.getElementById('cityField').value = code;
}
```

but when i am trying this it alerts null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this all the code you have? There would need to be some kind of call to the Google API before `place` would have any value.

Comment: No.I am calling Google API and the map is working properly.My need is that when i select a place in one txt box i want to populate another textbox with postal code

Comment: i will add my whole code

Answer (score 2):

Check the following links of SO and your problem's solution is in those question's answer:

1. [Lookup City and State by Zip Google Geocode Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749706/lookup-city-and-state-by-zip-google-geocode-api)
2. [How to look up ZIP/Postal Code by City using Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304404/how-to-look-up-zip-postal-code-by-city-using-google-maps-api)

And this one is good for you. Have a look:

[Google Maps API sometimes not returning PostalCode within AddressDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479938/google-maps-api-sometimes-not-returning-postalcode-within-addressdetails)

And read this tutorial:

[how-to-find-which-state-a-zip-code-is-located-in-using-the-google-maps-api](http://www.wearehathway.com/blog/tech/how-to-find-which-state-a-zip-code-is-located-in-using-the-google-maps-api)

Comment: @Anish so what you want exactly?